# How do I join two tables together without having to group by both clauses? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join two tables together in order to add the (sales rep) name associated with certain account information.

The main table is:

```
SELECT region, MAX(orders_total_usd) AS max_orders_total
 FROM
    (SELECT sales_reps.name AS sales_rep, region.name AS region, SUM(orders.total_amt_usd) AS orders_total_usd
    FROM sales_reps
    JOIN region
    ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
    JOIN accounts
    ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
    JOIN orders
    ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
    GROUP BY sales_rep, region
    ORDER BY orders_total_usd DESC) sub
GROUP BY region
```

What this table lists is the highest order totals (by sales_rep) for each region.

Now the thing is is that this table doesn't have the name of the sales rep. The reason is because when I try to add another column to this table (by pulling "sales_rep" from the table), it no longer just groups by the region (which is what I want--there are 4 regions), because I then have to add the sales_rep to the group by clause. So I tried to make this other table with sales_rep names, thinking that if I did that, I could then join them together and somehow it would only be the 4 regions and the 4 sales reps associated with that. 
Here is the second table:

```
SELECT sales_reps.name AS sales_rep, region.name AS region, SUM(orders.total_amt_usd) AS orders_total_usd
    FROM sales_reps
    JOIN region
    ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
    JOIN accounts
    ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
    JOIN orders
    ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
    GROUP BY sales_rep, region
    ORDER BY orders_total_usd DESC
```

But when I try to join these two tables together, I still basically get the same problem when I try to just add the sales reps names.

Gosh, I hope this makes some sense?

**Basically, that first section of code that I listed only has 4 rows (because there are 4 regions). But when I try to add the sales_rep column in there, it turns into like 50 rows (because there are 50 sales reps, and because i have to add the sales_rep to the group by clause). Is there any way to not add the sales rep to the group by clause? Because I only want there to be 4 rows! The 4 regions! And just the 4 sales reps associated with those order totals/regions!**

Any insight is appreciated!!
Thanks!!
Mark

Answer (score 0):

As you say, when you group in the outer query you lose the related columns (like the name). What you can do, is to number the rows in descending order for each region and pick the first one for each region. You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

For example:

```
with
sub as (
  SELECT
    sales_reps.name AS sales_rep, 
    region.name AS region, 
    SUM(orders.total_amt_usd) AS orders_total_usd
  FROM sales_reps
  JOIN region ON sales_reps.region_id = region.id
  JOIN accounts ON accounts.sales_rep_id = sales_reps.id
  JOIN orders ON orders.account_id = accounts.id
  GROUP BY sales_rep, region
),
b as (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by region order by order_total_usd desc) as rn
  from sub
)
SELECT region, orders_total_usd as max_orders_total
FROM b
WHERE rn = 1
```

Pay close attention to the `OVER()` clause. That's the one that defines which one is the first row, second row, etc. It sorts by `order_total_usd` descending. Finally the outer/last query just picks the first row per region using `rn = 1`.